# Form Submit Button Not Working in all browsers

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a simple form and all the fields are closed properly with tags. But whenever  submit button is clicked nothing happens.

The page has too much code so I am pasting the link here. Please use console to inspect element as right click is disabled. The Register Form is what I am talking about

http://www.topup2u.com/affiliate/index.php

Any help would be appreciated
Ahmar.

Comment: Why would you give as an url where the right click is disabled? There is for sure another div placed over your button.. that's why it is not working

Comment: You can still inspect element so why the down vote?

Comment: Because we can't spend our time by searching through all the website content.. we can't find the element which is on top of your button.. there is an element placed on your button.. that's why it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the reason that your button is not working:

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:69px;top:922px;width:600px;height:150px;z-index:12;" id="wb_Image28">
   <img style="width:600px;height:150px;" alt="" id="Image28" src="images/Divider-Line.png">
</div>
```

I've added it `display:none` and I've seen that the design was not affected. You should do it too.

Another way would be to find the right `z-index` value which will place the div behind the form and not on the top of it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to review your code around Image28 as it is displayed incorrectly. It covered over your button (as shown below).

```
<img id="Image28" style="width: 600px; height: 150px;" alt="" src="images/Divider-Line.png"/>
```

[image]